# How to select data within a range

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

Suppose I have some circular data [min >= 0, max < 360],

```
data = np.array([355.9,  2.47 ,  30.52, 5.33, 40.22, 340.22])
```

The circular mean of these data is `9`

I want to select the data around the mean by `+- 15` degrees. 
Therefore the selected data will be `new_data = [355.9,  2.47 ,  5.33]`. The selected data fall in the range between `[low=9-15, high=9+15] = [354, 24]`

What I have tried is

```
def remove_outliers(angles, mean, extend):

    high = (mean + extend) - 360 if (mean + extend)>360 else (mean + extend)
    low = (mean - extend) + 360 if (mean - extend)<0 else (mean - extend)

    angles = angles[angles>=low]
    angles = angles[angles<=high]

    return angles
```

`high = 24`, and `low = 354` but the next part is wrong

```
angles = angles[angles>=low] # this is wrong
angles = angles[angles<=high] # this is wrong

remove_outliers(data, 9, 15) # gives empty array
```

The function will work if the mean is above `15` or below `345` for `extend = 15`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you want, when low > high, the conditions should be `angles>=low` OR `angles<=high`, not `angles>=low` AND `angles<=high`. You can also use the `np.mod` function to get the high and low values.

I would write:

```
import numpy as np

def remove_outliers(angles, mean, extend):
    high = np.mod(mean+extend,360)
    low = np.mod(mean-extend,360)
    if high < low:
        return angles[(angles<=high) | (angles>=low)]
    else:
        return angles[(angles<=high) & (angles>=low)]


data = np.array([355.9,  2.47 ,  30.52, 5.33, 40.22, 340.22])


correct_angles = remove_outliers(data, 9, 15)
```

Comment: But this will not work if `data = array([173, 209, 166, 161, 163, 154, 166, 196, 176])` and the mean is `173.53`. I want the function to work for all cases. Thanks you very much for your feedback.

Comment: Thank you very much again, appreciate your help.